# JavaScript : Remove all duplicate elements from the internal arrays of the given 2-D array

Tags: javascript, arrays

You have to remove all duplicate elements from the internal arrays of the given 2-D array.

2-D Array

```
[[1,2,3,8,1,2], [54,26,14,54], [81,4,6,84]]
```

Internal arrays

```
[1,2,3,8,1,2], [54,26,14,54] and [81,4,6,84]
```

So the **output** should be something along the lines of

```
[[1,2,3,8],[54,26,15],[81,4,6,84]]
```

Code:

```js
var twoD = [[1,2,3,8,1,2], [54,26,14,54], [81,4,6,84]];
function deleteDuplicate (twoD) {
        let uniqueArr = []; //init empty array
    for(var i=0;i<twoD.length;i++){
        for(let j of twoD[i]) {
        if(uniqueArr.indexOf(j) === -1) {   
            uniqueArr.push(j);
        }
    }
    }
     return uniqueArr;
}

console.log(deleteDuplicate(twoD));
```

My code `returns` a **single** array with `[1,2,3,8,54,26,15,81,4,6,84]` as values.

I know the issues lie in the pushing but I am unable to think of anyway, how should I do it?

Comment: This function waits a twoD parameter. However you have set a var twoD in second line. Other hand you should use recursion.

Comment: Here some more ways you can try :-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20339466/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-a-two-dimensional-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

```js
const arr = [[1,2,3,8,1,2], [54,26,14,54], [81,4,6,84]];


function beUnique(arr){
  const res = arr.map((a)=>{
    const unique = new Set(a);
    return Array.from(unique);
  });
  console.log(res);
}

beUnique(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you Kyun , I'll go read about sets.If you don't mind can you explain the code for a novice.

Comment: @ShubhanshuRai `Set` has unique elements only. I just use the spec of `Set`.

Answer (score 2):

### Issue

- You are adding values that satisfy the `if` condition into **one array `uniqueArr`**. That is why the result is 1D array.

**Here is the problematic part:**

```
if(uniqueArr.indexOf(j) === -1) {   
  uniqueArr.push(j);
}
```

### Solution

- Use `.map()` to modify each inner array.
- Use `new Set()` to remove duplicate elements.

```js
var twoD = [
  [1, 2, 3, 8, 1, 2],
  [54, 26, 14, 54],
  [81, 4, 6, 84]
];

function deleteDuplicate(arr) {
  return arr.map(e => [...new Set(e)]);
}

console.log(deleteDuplicate(twoD));
```

### Tips

Here is how to remove duplicate elements from an array.

```
let arr = [1,1,3,4,5,3];
let newArr = [...new Set(arr)]; // -> [1,3,4,5]
```

Comment: I like your solution @Miu.   `twoD.map(x => new Set(x))`

Comment: Thank you, Josiah :) I like a single line of code.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one

```js
function deleteDuplicate (twoD) {
    var twoD = [[1,2,3,8,1,2], [54,26,14,54], [81,4,6,84]];
        let uniqueArr = []; //init empty array
        let uniqueSubArr = [];
        
    for(var i=0;i<twoD.length;i++){
            uniqueSubArr = [];
        
        for(let j of twoD[i]) {
          if(uniqueArr.indexOf(j) === -1) {   
              uniqueSubArr.push(j);
          }
        }
      
    uniqueArr.push(uniqueSubArr);
    }
     return uniqueArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Using Array.protototype.map(), Array.prototype.reduce() and Array.prototype.includes().`

```js
function deleteDuplicate(arr) {
  return arr.map((numbers) => {
    return numbers.reduce((acc, num) => {
      if (!acc.includes(num)) {
        acc.push(num);
      }
      return acc;
    }, []);
  });
}

console.log(
  deleteDuplicate([
    [1, 2, 3, 8, 1, 2],
    [54, 26, 14, 54],
    [81, 4, 6, 84],
  ])
);
```