# Google Apps Script - Remove duplicates in all sheets with one function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, duplicates

I have this code from another question that works perfectly for me, but I'd like to get it to remove the duplicates of every sheet and not just the currently active one. This is also for large spreadsheets with a lot of data, so I have to keep the 6min execution time maximum in mind as well. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here's my code:

```
function removeDuplicates() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().removeDuplicates();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following modification?

#### From:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().removeDuplicates();
```

#### To:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().forEach(sheet => sheet.getDataRange().removeDuplicates());
```

- In this modification, all sheets are retrieved with `getSheets()` and the duplicated rows of each sheet is removed with `removeDuplicates()` in a loop.

#### References:

- [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [removeDuplicates()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#removeduplicates)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Michael Hawk Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.