# Use Zapier to Remove Duplicates (Based on single column) from Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, zapier

I need to remove duplicates from a Google Sheet based on a single column.
Within Sheets this functionality exists but I cannot find a way to do this as part of a Zapier automation (zap).

Answer (score 0):

In this case that sounds more like a feature within the App that you are trying to use, within sheets this can be done doing the following:

- Highlight the data you'd like to include, and click Data > Data Cleanup > Remove duplicates.

I verified on Zapier and they seem to provide similar actions on this [blog](https://zapier.com/blog/remove-duplicates-google-sheets/).

Comment: I understand how to do this in the app; but I am trying to do this step as part of automated process. Is there a way of automating this via some app / tool?

Comment: If you want to automatize it you could use App Script instead using the `removeDuplicates()` method or even the Spreadsheets API, there is a good example in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67202956/google-apps-script-remove-duplicates-in-large-spreadsheets/67205670#67205670)